# How to parse JSON containing HTML as HTML

Tags: javascript, html, json, web

I want to parse a JSON object `response.indexText` which contains HTML tags (validated with JSONLint).

```
{
  "indexText": "<div id=\"content-home\"><h1> Hello World! <\/h1> <p>Some text.<\/p><p>Some more text.<\/p></div>"
}
```

into `<div id="indexText"></div>`
But when I use (**EDIT after first answer. window.onload inside and outside does not change the problem.**)

```
window.onload = function () {
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        let response = JSON.parse(xhttp.responseText);
        document.getElementById("indexText").innerHTML = response.indexText;
    }
};
xhttp.open("GET", "./json/en.json", true);
xhttp.send();  
};
```

and ***reload the page it will be empty***. What is going wrong? How can I parse the JSON content such that the client will render the content as HTML?

What I am trying to do. At the moment my page consists of multiple *.html files. All pages have the same navigation bar and the same footer. Only the content does change. Now I am trying to store the content inside of my JSON file such that I can change the text when clicking navigation links.

Answer (score 1):

Put your code inside [window.onload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onload) and you will get your required result.

Check the below working code:

```js
window.onload = function() {
var response = {
  "indexText": "<div id=\"content-home\"><h1> Hello World! <\/h1> <p>Some text.<\/p><p>Some more text.<\/p></div>"
};

document.getElementById("indexText").innerHTML = response.indexText;
};
```

```html
<div id="indexText"></div>
```

Working JSfiddle here : https://jsfiddle.net/y2rkhp8g/1/

Comment: it's interesting that no 'un-escaping' was required, can you explain why this works?

Comment: shouldn't the div also be `<\/div>` ? @VicJordan

Comment: plus one for your answer. But that does not solve my problem. I edited my question. Did I correctly implement your answer?

Comment: @MrYouMath No, you are not implementing my answer correctly. Put ALL your JavaScript code inside window.onload function. It will work.

Comment: you mean window.load = function () { Everthing inside this};? Tried that but it didn't work.

Comment: @VicJordan: The same problem persists the html formatted content is not displayed.

Comment: @VicJordan: I tried to run your code on JSFiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/h8erfq17/) and it does not work, even if I rewrite `<\/div>`.

Comment: @MrYouMath your JSfiddle is not correct. You did not add `<div id="indexText"></div>` and also in jsfiddle default setting is `onload` event so you don't need to explicitly add `window.onload` in jsfiddle code. Check this working jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/y2rkhp8g/1/